# Create NSMutableDictionsry in Swifty-Json

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swifty-json

I want to create a NSMutableDictionary using Swifty-Json.
I have declared dictionary like this

```
   var arrTest = Array<JSON>()

   var testDict : JSON = [:]

  testDict.dictionaryObject?.updateValue(arrTest[0]["test"][indexPath.item]["xyz"], forKey: "abc")
```

1. Now I am unable to setValueForKey in this Dictionary.
   Can Someone tell me how to create a NSMutableDictionary using SwiftyJson and also how to insert, update and delete values in this dictionary.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to make one NSMutableArray, and using for loop you have to add one by one value into NSMutableArray and then update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// add object

 let testobj = ["qwe" : arrTest[0]["test"][indexPath.item]["xyz"]]

dictSelectedOption = JSON(testobj)

//remove objects

dictSelectedOption.dictionaryObject?.removeAll()
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift, use Swift built-in type `Dictionary` instead. Declaring it as `var` will make it mutable.

You also don't use `updateValue` for `Dictionary`, simply use a subscript:

`var testDict : [String : AnyObject] = [:]`
`let key = "abc"`
`let value = arrTest[0]["test"][indexPath.item]["xyz"]`
`testDict[key] = value`